# A definition of ordered field

Tags: ordered-fields

**Definition**: An *ordered field* is field $F$ equipped with a linear order $<$ such that

- $1 > 0$
- For any $a,b \in F$, $$ a,b > 0 \quad \Longrightarrow \quad a+b,\;ab > 0.$$

I like this definition - it's quite clean - but I'm not convinced it is equivalent to other definitions of the notion *ordered field*. To elaborate, suppose $F$ is a field, linearly ordered by $<$ as per the definition above. The first result that stands out is $(\ast)$ ... $$a > 0 \Longrightarrow -a < 0.$$ This can be proven by contradiction. For say $a > 0$ but $-a \geqslant 0$. Since $a$ is not itself zero (irreflexivity), its additive inverse is not zero either, and $-a > 0$. Since the linear order with which we are working is such that the sum of elements greater than zero is again greater than zero, we obtain the contradiction $$0 = a + (-a) > 0.$$

Using $(\ast)$, it's not difficult to show that for any $b \in F$, the following relations are mutually exclusive ... $$b > 0, \quad -b > 0, \quad b = 0.$$
For instance, if say $-b > 0$, then applying $(\ast)$ to $a := -b > 0$ we determine $b= -a < 0$, whence by the properties of linear order it is not possible that $b>0$ or $b=0$.

So *at most* one of the aforementioned three relations can occur (great!), but why must *any* occur at all. I ultimately need to prove $(\ast\ast)$ ...
$$a < 0 \quad \Longrightarrow \quad -a > 0,$$
but I am not sure where to start such a proof, as the definition for ordered field I am working with doesn't say anything about elements less than zero. It is now when I think the definition I have is incomplete. Can $(\ast\ast)$ be deduced?

Comment: any of three must occur because of definition of linear order: any two are compatible

Comment: How so? The definition of linear order ensures that $b > 0$ or $b < 0$ or $b = 0$ must occur, but it is not obvious from my definition of ordered field that $b < 0$ is the same as $- b > 0$.

Comment: no it's not, my comment is for you first question: "but why must any occur at all"

Comment: @AnatoliyR:  I suspect you meant "any two are incompatible."  The OP seems to appreciate that *at most* one of the trichotomy cases holds, and wants to prove *at least* one case holds (for any $a$).  The last edit was shortly before your Comment, so perhaps you were looking at an older revision?

Comment: I am trying to prove that a < b => a + c < b + c and I cannot. It does not seem that a, b > 0 => a + b > o is equivalent

Comment: The equality $b-a = (b+c) - (a+c)$ comes to mind, and I have a feeling the validity of the implication $a < b \Longrightarrow a+c < b+c$ could be known if the validity of an equivalence like $x < y \Longleftrightarrow y - x > 0$ were known. For instance, if said equivalence were known, you might argue that "$a < b$ implies $(b+c) - (a+c) = b - a >0$, further implying $a+c < b+c$". Of course, I am also led to believe that the desired equivalence very much depends on the validity of $(\ast\ast)$

Comment: @hardmath I mean exactly what I meant, but I did not recognize the question properly, so my comment was wrong - see my answer and what I think about this definition for ordered field.

Comment: What is your source for that bad definition? Did you find that in a textbook?

Comment: I saw it here https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ordered+field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathbb N=\{0,1,2,\dots\}$, the natural numbers including zero. Define a linear order $\lt$ on $\mathbb R$ so that $a\lt b$ has the usual meaning if $a,b\in\mathbb N$ or if $a,b\in\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb N$, but $a\lt b$ whenever $a\in\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb N$ and $b\in\mathbb N$. Your faulty definition of "ordered field" is satisfied, since $a\gt0$ just means that $a$ is a (real) positive integer; but $\frac12\lt0$ and $-\frac12\lt0$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a field of Real numbers with such an order:

1. All rational number have standard real order.
2. All irrational numbers are less than 0 and for real irrational a, b, when -b < -a < 0 < a < b in standard real order we define -b < b < -a < a < 0
3. Standard order definition between standard negative rational numbers and standard negative irrational numbers.

This field seems to be an ordered field (in your definition), however your (**) is incorrect!

If you find a mistake - tell me, I cannot see it.

Comment: Really it doesn't matter how the irrationals are ordered at all, as long as you just make them all negative.

Comment: Right, but then you have to prove that such a linear order exists :-) actually, it is, because cardinality is continuum, so you can make it isomorphic to a set of real numbers

Comment: also need to specify rule between negative rational and irrational, e.g. any irrational is less than any rational, but either way it works; finally you can replace rational with any other strict sub-field